# How to use custom component inside PipeTransform in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular-pipe

I would like to use my custom component Status inside my pipe transform, but it doesn't work.

The browser displays only the value without `< Status />`. It's like my component is not called.

Why? How to solve that please?

Component Status has been added to the app module.

**status.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'status'
})
export class StatusPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): string {
    let status = '<Status type="ok"><b>' + value + '</b></Status>';
    return status;
  }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<td [innerHtml]="result.status | status"></td>
```

**status.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'Status',
    template: '<span class="status status--{{ type }}">
      <span class="status__message">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
      </span>
   </span>',
   styleUrls: ['./status.component.css'],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})
export class StatusComponent {

    @Input() type:any;    

}
```

Comment: That is not what pipes are for or how to use them.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? I'm not sure if I got what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to give it HTML values when it should be text values.

Try this :

```
<span [innerHTML]="yourValue | status"></span>
```

Instead of

```
<span>{{yourValue | status}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks but I already use <span [innerHTML]="yourValue | status"></span>. The "<b></b>" works.

Comment: Please edit your post to show how you call your pipe. Did you declare your pipe and exported it ?

Comment: Done. Everything is declared.

Comment: Because it's `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`

Comment: Nope, it's not that. I said "<b />" works, and it's "<b />" HTML.

Comment: You mean you want to add one of your custom components with a pipe?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point. You can't, pipes are transformed after build. You need to use a component, not a pipe.